# удаление std::vector<cv::Rect> элементов , входящих в другой вектор

Tags: c++, opencv

у меня есть два вектора std::vector<cv::Rect> v1 и std::vector<cv::Rect> v2. Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу из v1 удалить элементы, которые находятся внутри элементов v2.
я пишу

```
    v1.erase(std::remove_if(v1.begin(),
                                        v1.end(),
                                        [&v2](cv::Rect r, cv::Rect f) {
                                            for (auto f : v2)
                                                return ((r & f) == r);
                                        }),
                         v1.end());
```

но элементы не удаляются

Comment: *"я пишу"* - ¿и что не так с этим кодом?

Comment: Вообще-то в [`remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) передается унарный предикат, у вас же он бинарный... Да и работает он у вас как-то странно ("странно, если не сказать большего" (с))

Comment: можно подробнее, пожалуйста, как правильно это  написать?

Comment: проблема решена, спасибо